# Pygame error "Video system not initialized" on ubuntu server with only terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I'm using pygame on a PC (PC-104) with ubuntu server, for this reason it only has terminal, not UI.

On my laptop the code works perfecly, running the code on the terminal "eg: python game.py", but on the PC104 it gives "Video system not initialized", I read the error is shown because it is a way to use events on a system without UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank for your answer jsbueno. I was able to found a solution a few weeks ago but forget to answer the question.

I wasn't able to run any pygame script with any other library than X11. But I found that one can run the script with no graphics library. Just setting the SDL_VIDEOLIBRARY enviroment variable to "dummy".

This is posible on bash but I prefer to do it on python:

```
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

With this I was able to run the pygame script, detect joystick events, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to run pygame programs in a system without X11 if you set it to use framebuffer  or vgalib - the docs even talk about using aalib (which would display graphics using ascii art on the terminal.)

This part of the documentation has it:

> Pygame will select from one of several internal display backends when
>   it is initialized. The display mode will be chosen depending on the
>   platform and permissions of current user. Before the display module is
>   initialized the environment variable SDL_VIDEODRIVER can be set to
>   control which backend is used. The systems with multiple choices are
>   listed here.
>
> Windows : windib, directx
>      Unix    : x11, dga, fbcon, directfb,
>   ggi, vgl, svgalib, aalib

So, what you have to do is set the SDL_VIDEODRIVER environment variable before starting your code. And being shure the proper lib. is installed.

For more information:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html